# using Vimeo in C#

Tags: c#, .net, vimeo

Get All Albums - just need the titles and identifier

Get List of all Channels - just need the titles and identifier

e.g. http://vimeo.com/channels/165628/videos/rss

I have tried its API but plz can u help me how can i do this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Checkout these API wrappers:

- http://vimeocsharp.codeplex.com/
- http://www.robgreen.me/post/Getting-Started-With-The-Vimeo-API-in-C.aspx